# React Native Environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

-Sorry for my bad English.
-Im newbie at this REACT NATIVE. When I hit "npm start" on cmd as admin, this errors as below.
-Im spent hours fixing but it seems like no changes. Thank you guys for helping me.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ASUS\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ASUS\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-21T17_54_27_222Z-debug.log
```

-- ``And here the file log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\ASUS/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ASUS\package.json'
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\ASUS
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
9 verbose node v12.18.4
10 verbose npm  v6.14.6
11 error code ENOENT
12 error syscall open
13 error path C:\Users\ASUS\package.json
14 error errno -4058
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ASUS\package.json'
16 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: I think you are running the command from the wrong directory. The line that begins with `5 verbose...` indicates that there is no package.json in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

you need to goto the project folder and do npm start from there. For example, if you initialized your project in C:\MyAwesomeProject, you will need to be in that same folder.